# What does the "<>" mean in "kill -9 <>"?

Tags: command-line, kill

I am going through [a tutorial](http://pgpen.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/recoverability-of-postgresql-2-setup-of.html) on recovering from a database failure and in the tutorial, a failure on the host of the primary database is simulated with:

```
kill -9 <>
```

I know that the `kill` command is used to send a signal to a process, and that `9` represents the `SIGKILL` signal that terminates a process, but what does the `<>` argument stand for?

I have read the manual pages for the `kill` command but still cannot figure out why and what for `<>` is used.

Comment: Can you add the link to the tutorial? The first thing that comes to mind, is that the author of that post wants you to replace the `<>` characters with a specific process id.

Comment: It looks like the author of the site messed up with HTML strings. The source code has: `kill&nbsp;-9 &lt;<pid for="" nbsp="" postmaster="" process="">&gt;</pid>`, so they probably wrote `kill -9 <pid>` and some funny editor did all the magic to create a `<pid>` tag.

Comment: @fedorqui, `<pid for="" nbsp="" postmaster="" process="">`, that makes perfect sense! It's meant to say "pid for postmaster process" and it is the main PostgreSQL PID to kill. So the post was meant to say `kill -9 <pid for postmaster process>` Mystery solved.

Comment: Heads up: Don't make `kill -9` a habit. Just use `kill`. SIGTERM lets the process shut down gracefully. SIGKILL (`-9`) is the nuclear option.

Comment: @fedorqui: I'm pretty sure it was kill -9 <<pid>>.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're supposed to replace the `<>` by the process id.
To get the process id, you can use the command

```
ps -aux
```

It will list all the processes, and you just have to choose the right process

If you have a single instance of a process, you can also use the `pkill` commmand with the name of the process, 
eg

```
pkill -9 mysql
```

Comment: ... and if there are multiple instances, you can use `killall`. Also, if you want the PID, `pgrep` saves hunting through `ps` output

Comment: @Zanna pkill actually kills all the processes that match, not just one.

Comment: keep in mind that pkill would kill any process containing the `mysql` word. For example, if you have a process called `mysql` and another `mysql-python` (just an example) both would be killed with that command.

Answer (score 3):

It is

```
<pid> [...]
      Send signal to every <pid> listed.
```

in manpage. There is always description inside of the `<>` quotes.

Answer (score 2):

#### `<>` in the man page means replace `<>` with PID.

In addition to the [answer by Felicien](https://askubuntu.com/a/1006091/527764) using the `ps` command, you can also use `top` or `htop`

```
top -d 10
```

Use `-d <>` (duration) to update every `<>` seconds.

To kill the process, simply note the PID and kill the process ID with:

```
kill -9 xxxx
```

Note: for `htop`, you will need to type `htop -d 100` ie; `10` seconds.